# Create location route to subdirectory

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to create a **Preview** URL for my project. Each User has some directorys (home directory) on the drive, which contains a folder named `/docs/`.

When the user calls their URL (for example `https://preview.example.com/microsoft/VisualStudioCode`):

`http(s)://preview.example.com/<company>/<project>/`

How i can tell **nginx**, that he should internal append the `/docs` to the URL?

Following Directory structure is given:

```
 - /opt
   - /users
     - <company>
       - <project>
       - <project>
     - /microsoft
       - /VisualStudioCode
         - /docs
         - /downloads
         - /temp
         - config.json
```

The *DocumentRoot* of nginx is by default `/opt/users/` and the `<company>/<project>` exists as a real directory.

How i can create an `Alias` or another configuration to navigate to the `/docs` directory, if the user opens the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the rest of your nginx.conf is set up correctly you'd have to add this server block:

```
server {
  server_name preview.example.com;
  root /opt/users;

  location / {
    try_files $uri/docs =404;
  }
}
```

If you want to serve ANY file from within the secret docs directory then you're gonna have to do regex in your location block, like so:

```
location ~ ^/(?<company>.+)/(?<project>.+)/(?<filepath>.+)$ {
  try_files /$company/$project/docs/$filepath =404;
}
```